# Drag and drop a file or O365 attachment to a view and creates a new doc with the dropped file attached

Tags: lotusscript

I can not find any documentation about such possibility - is there a workaround ??
The view is a notes view and application is used with notes 10.0.1FP4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such possibility. You can only Drag & Drop Attachments in existing documents.